"Contents of this page have been moved" when trying to integrate glassdoor salaries widget
I am trying to integrate glassdoor salaries widget in my webpage. Below is the endpoint:
https://www.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?version=1&action=salaries&t.s=w-m&format=270x250-chart&location=US&t.a=i&responseType=embed
That the widget loads, but when I enter company and location, and hit search, then it redirects me to the glassdoor page displaying "contents of this page have been moved". There is no documentation available on the glassdoor page, nor available anywhere on the internet. Can someone kindly help me with this?

Widget is deprecated. They will remove the support.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
